# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate cucumber test runner

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testing, cucumber

hi guys im trying to run my cucumber framework using testng, im pretty sure im a version issue but id appreciate it if someone can point the problem here thanks

features:

```
Feature: Application Login

Scenario: Home page default login
Given user is on landing page
When user logins into the application with username "jon" and password 
"1234"
Then Home page is displayed
And Cards displayed "true"

Scenario: Home page default login2
Given user is on landing page
When user logins into the application with username "john" and password 
"4321"
Then Home page is displayed
And Cards displayed "false"
```

Definitions:

```
package StepDefinations;

import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;



public class LoginDefination {

    @Given("^user is on landing page$")
    public void user_is_on_landing_page() throws Throwable {
        //code
        System.out.println("on landing page");
        }


    @When("^user logins into the application with username and password$")
    public void user_logins_into_the_application_with_username_and_password() throws Throwable {
        //code
        System.out.println("logging in");

    }

    @When("^user logins into the application with username \"([^\"]*)\" and password \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void user_logins_into_the_application_with_something_and_password_something(String strArg1, String strArg2) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(strArg1 +" "+ strArg2);
    }

    @Then("^Home page is displayed$")
    public void home_page_is_displayed() throws Throwable {
        //code
        System.out.println("hello homepage");
    }

    @And("^Cards are displayed$")
    public void cards_are_displayed() throws Throwable {
        //code
        System.out.println("hello cards");
    }

    @And("^Cards are not displayed$")
    public void cards_are_not_displayed() throws Throwable {
        //code
        System.out.println("hello not cards");
    }

    @And("^Cards displayed \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void cards_displayed(String args) throws Throwable {
        //code
        System.out.println("this will or will not display the cards - " + args);
    }

}
```

test runner file:

```
package CucumberOptions;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

//Feature

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src\\test\\java\\features",
        //if u want tp execute everything then just give the path till the package level
        glue= "StepDefinations"//Package name
        )
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

testng xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="cucumber testing 101">
  <classes>
  <class name="CucumberOptions.testme"/>
  <class name="CucumberOptions.TestRunner"/>

  </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

maven pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>Automation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Automation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <build>
  <resources>

 <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
 </resource>

  </resources>
  <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

</plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>



  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5</version>
</dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency> 




  </dependencies>
</project>
```

error:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.10.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class CucumberOptions.TestRunner
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:363)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:275)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:191)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:100)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:78)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:41)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:252)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:222)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:171)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_10$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_10.java:28)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_10$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_10.java:61)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:623)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:189)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:136)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1375)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1355)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.<init>(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:27)
    at CucumberOptions.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:14)
    ... 30 more
```

its a simple piece of code but im just trying to make it work using testng then maven, if someone can help me out i will be very thankful :)

Answer (score 0):

Incompatible versions of TestNG and Cucumber libraries. Validate the versions of them in your dependency tree and check what version of TestNG fits to the version of your Cucumber library, for example here:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng

UPDATE: I noticed that you have actually posted your `pom.xml`

Update the version of `cucumber-testng` to `1.2.5` (use the same version as for `cucumber-java`). Use `testng` version `6.9.10` (if you do not mind). This way you will align all libraries versions.

**CONFIRMED:** You have a conflict between `cucumber-testng` ver. 1.1.5 and `cucumber-java` ver. 1.2.5. Set both libraries to either version `1.1.5`, or update them to use version `1.2.5`.

Comment: im such a potato, i thought i had the same versions , ty!